# How to connect web sockets between Spring Boot and Angular with Spring Security?

Tags: angular, spring, spring-security, websocket, sockjs

I'm working on a real time chat project using web sockets in Spring Boot and Angular. i'm using Spring Security in my api.

Here is my WebSocketConfig in api :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/socket")
                .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*")
                .withSockJS();
    }
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
                .enableSimpleBroker("/message");
    }
}
```

and here is my controller :

```
@Controller
public class WebSocketController {

    private final SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    WebSocketController(SimpMessagingTemplate template){
        this.template = template;
    }

    @MessageMapping("/send/message")
    public void sendMessage(String message){
        System.out.println(message);
        this.template.convertAndSend("/message",  message);
    }
}
```

When I send a request with Postman on 'http://localhost:8080/socket, it works

Now, this is my Angular service to set up the connection :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
declare var SockJS: any;
declare var Stomp: any;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class WebSocketService {
  
  constructor() {
    this.initializeWebSocketConnection();
  }
  stompClient: any;
  msg: string[] = [];
  initializeWebSocketConnection() {
    const serverUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/socket';
    const ws = new SockJS(serverUrl);
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(ws);
    const that = this;
    this.stompClient.connect({}, function(frame: any) {
      that.stompClient.subscribe('/message', (message: any) => {
        if (message) {
          that.msg.push(message);
        }
      });
    });
  }
  
  sendMessage(message: string) {
    this.stompClient.send('/app/send/message' , {}, message);
  }
}
```

SockJs.min.js and stomp.min.js are both declared in my index.html file.

When I'm testing this connection from my client angular, I get the following error :
[image]

I don't have any error in api console, and I don't know why I'm getting this forbidden error.

Does anyone know why ? Thank you very much !

Comment: if you add spring security to your project it will automatically enable the default security settings locking everything down. You need to configure spring security to your liking. Read the docs, on the webpage. Also, learn how to enable spring security debug logs to se the reasons for the different statusccodes in your log.

Answer (score 0):

`setAllowedOrigins("*")` may not work as expected with authentication.

You may need to add your origins explicitly. (for example `["http://localhost:4200"]` )

Also, you may get more information by debugging the interceptors.

```
org.springframework.security.messaging.web.socket: DEBUG
org.springframework.web.socket.server: DEBUG
```

potential duplicate of [Failed to send message to ExecutorSubscribableChannel[clientInboundChannel]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34585828/failed-to-send-message-to-executorsubscribablechannelclientinboundchannel/77677499#77677499)